# v4l.c:52:28: fatal error: linux/videodev.h: No such file or directory

Tags: drivers, video, webcam, gpu-driver, camera

I am trying to install the driver for PS3 eye camera in Ubuntu 16.04 however using [this tutorial](http://plopes.org/ps3eye-in-ubuntu-tutorial/), after the `make` command, I get the following error:

```
Making all in cpi
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/mona/unicap-0.9.5/cpi'
Making all in v4l
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/mona/unicap-0.9.5/cpi/v4l'
/bin/bash ../../libtool --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../.. -I../include -I../../include    -g -O2 -MT queue.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/queue.Tpo -c -o queue.lo queue.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../.. -I../include -I../../include -g -O2 -MT queue.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/queue.Tpo -c queue.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/queue.o
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../.. -I../include -I../../include -g -O2 -MT queue.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/queue.Tpo -c queue.c -o queue.o >/dev/null 2>&1
mv -f .deps/queue.Tpo .deps/queue.Plo
/bin/bash ../../libtool --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../.. -I../include -I../../include    -g -O2 -MT v4l.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/v4l.Tpo -c -o v4l.lo v4l.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../.. -I../include -I../../include -g -O2 -MT v4l.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/v4l.Tpo -c v4l.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/v4l.o
v4l.c:52:28: fatal error: linux/videodev.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
Makefile:387: recipe for target 'v4l.lo' failed
make[3]: *** [v4l.lo] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/mona/unicap-0.9.5/cpi/v4l'
Makefile:315: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/mona/unicap-0.9.5/cpi'
Makefile:414: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/mona/unicap-0.9.5'
Makefile:344: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

current path is:

```
$ pwd
/home/mona/unicap-0.9.5
```

How should I fix this or install the driver for PS3 eye camera?

When trying smallapp I get no video as mentioned in the answer.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Intro

Please note that *unified interface to video capture devices* is packaged in Ubuntu as [`libunicap2-dev`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&keywords=libunicap2-dev&searchon=names) package.

But it seems that you are patching the exact 0.9.5 version from 2008 year.

## 1. Compilation

So you should enable source code packages from *Software & Updates* (or `software-properties-gtk` command)

[image: Software & Updates]

and install all build-dependencies with

```
sudo apt-get build-dep libunicap2-dev
```

if you need X11 support (GTK-widget) install Xv library with

```
sudo apt-get install libxv-dev
```

and then follow your guide:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget http://unicap-imaging.org/downloads/unicap-0.9.5.tar.gz
tar -xf unicap-0.9.5.tar.gz
cd unicap-0.9.5
wget http://kaswy.free.fr/sites/default/files/download/ps3eye/unicap/unicap-gspca.patch
patch -p0 < unicap-gspca.patch cpi/v4l2cpi/v4l2.c
./configure
```

### 1.1 Patching for current Ubuntu version

As you already know some include-paths were changed since blog-post (sooner or later in 2010). So we need to patch them:

*cpi/v4l/v4l.c*

```
cat << EOF > xenial-v4l-p1.patch

--- ~/Downloads/unicap-0.9.5/cpi/v4l/v4l.c
+++ ~/Downloads/unicap-0.9.12/cpi/v4l/v4l.c
@@ -49,7 +49,7 @@
 #endif
 #include <debug.h>

-#include <linux/videodev.h>
+#include <libv4l1-videodev.h>
 #include <linux/videodev2.h> // for v4l2 checks

 #include "v4l.h"

EOF

patch -p0 < xenial-v4l-p1.patch cpi/v4l/v4l.c
```

*cpi/v4l2cpi/uvcvideo.h*

```
cat << EOF > xenial-v4l-p2.patch
--- ~/Downloads/unicap-0.9.5/cpi/v4l2cpi/uvcvideo.h
+++ ~/Downloads/unicap-0.9.12/cpi/v4l2cpi/uvcvideo.h
@@ -2,7 +2,7 @@
 #define _USB_VIDEO_H_

 #include <linux/kernel.h>
-#include <linux/videodev.h>
+#include <libv4l1-videodev.h>

 #include "uvc_compat.h"


EOF

patch -p0 < xenial-v4l-p2.patch cpi/v4l2cpi/uvcvideo.h
```

Then make and install:

```
make
sudo make install
```

## 2. Testing

It seems that examples are located in *examples*, we can compile them with:

```
sudo apt-get install libsdl-dev libjpeg-turbo8-dev
cd examples
make
```

one interesting is GTK-application in *examples/unicapgtk/smallapp*

```
env LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib/ unicapgtk/smallapp/smallapp
```

Also you can try to get information about camera

```
env LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib/ c/device_info/device_info
```

---

To view the video you may need to install [UCView](http://unicap-imaging.org/ucview.htm), but I do not know how to do this.

Comment: how should I fix this? $ sudo apt-get build-dep libunicap2-dev 
Reading package lists... Done
E: You must put some 'source' URIs in your sources.list

Comment: I can't find `software-properties-gtk` in Software & Updates. How should I find it?

Comment: your solution did not work. After I installed the package you mentioned and did a fresh install of the one I mentioned in this post, I still get the same error.

Comment: hey it did not work. After I followed your command I got same error right after make.

Comment: libunicapgtk:       no ( required Xv extensions not found ) 
would this be related? I don't know how to fix it. I get this as a result of ./configure

Comment: so after I installed the package you mentioned, I didn't have any problem (all Yes) in ./configure but make still fails with libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../.. -I../include -I../../include -g -O2 -MT v4l.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/v4l.Tpo -c v4l.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/v4l.o
v4l.c:52:28: fatal error: linux/videodev.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
Makefile:387: recipe for target 'v4l.lo' failed

Comment: You need to patch the code before make as described in the answer. Just copy gray lines and paste them to the terminal.

Comment: so I am not exactly sure what I should do after ./configure. Which file I should change and what is the exact line I should change. I guess I am not following what is the change I should make based on diffs you showed

Comment: please have a look at the screenshot here https://askubuntu.com/questions/1048663/e-unable-to-locate-package-libunicapgtk2-dev still not getting any video :(

Comment: You can try to compile *smallapp* as described above.

Comment: please check the screenshot result of running smallapp in my question. still no video

Comment: I'm sorry but I have no more ideas. We are trying to compile program from 2008 in 2018. If you have time you may try to install Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and compile all the stuff here. But buying new camera may be an option too.  (I cleaned up my comments - answer contains all of them, you can do the same for other readers/users).