# E: Unable to locate package libunicapgtk2-dev

Tags: package-management, video, gtk, gpu-driver

How should I install libunicapgtk2-dev for Ubuntu 16.04?

```
mona@Mona:~/unicap-0.9.5$ sudo apt-get update
Get:1 file:/var/nvinfer-runtime-trt-repo-3.0.4-ga-cuda9.0  InRelease
Ign:1 file:/var/nvinfer-runtime-trt-repo-3.0.4-ga-cuda9.0  InRelease
Get:2 file:/var/nvinfer-runtime-trt-repo-3.0.4-ga-cuda9.0  Release [574 B]
Get:2 file:/var/nvinfer-runtime-trt-repo-3.0.4-ga-cuda9.0  Release [574 B]
Hit:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/otto-kesselgulasch/gimp/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                                 
Hit:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                    
Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [109 kB]
Hit:7 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease
Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease [107 kB]
Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [107 kB]
Get:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [318 kB]
Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [224 kB]
Get:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [246 kB]
Get:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [334 kB]
Get:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [5,964 B]
Get:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [3,328 B]
Get:16 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [5,096 B]
Get:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [67.7 kB]
Get:18 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [68.0 kB]
Get:19 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [107 kB]
Get:20 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [142 kB]
Fetched 1,843 kB in 1s (1,397 kB/s)                                    
Reading package lists... Done
mona@Mona:~/unicap-0.9.5$ sudo apt-get install libunicapgtk2-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libunicapgtk2-dev
```

[image]

Comment: This package is available only [for Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (EOL or paid ESM)](https://pkgs.org/download/libunicapgtk2-dev). Usually it is very hard to install packages from previous Ubuntu on current one. Are you sure that you chose correct way? Why you need UniCap? Does `guvcview` see your camera?

Comment: $ guvcview
GUVCVIEW: version 2.0.2
GUVCVIEW: couldn't open /home/mona/.config/guvcview2/video0 for read: No such file or directory
V4L2_CORE: ERROR opening V4L interface: No such file or directory
Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.